# How do I centralize a group of divs, leaving the last one aligned to the left?

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to layout a group of divs, with class `cards`, centralized by a div with class `card-wrapper` and yet have the remaining `.cards` in the last row to align left, as seen in the wireframe.

The idea is that if I have a narrow screen width, the layout can become 3 or 2 or even 1 column but the whole wrapper is always centered but the `.cards` in the last row to align left.

[image: Desired Effect]

Here is my code.

CSS

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.cards-wrapper{
  background: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card{
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="cards-wrapper">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
  <div class="card">6</div>
  <div class="card">7</div>
  <div class="card">8</div>
  <div class="card">9</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/onestaryx/pen/RXNRRx)

Comment: Can you use CSS grid?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code as follow.

**HTML**

```
<div class="cards-wrapper">
    <div class="cards-wrapper-inner">
      <div class="card">1</div>
      <div class="card">2</div>
      <div class="card">3</div>
      <div class="card">4</div>
      <div class="card">5</div>
      <div class="card">6</div>
      <div class="card">7</div>
      <div class="card">8</div>
      <div class="card">9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.cards-wrapper{
  background: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
.cards-wrapper-inner {
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  align-items: center;
  width: 93%;
  margin: 0 auto
}

.card{
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Grid makes this very easy, [if you can support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.cards-wrapper{
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* change display to grid and set up columns, gaps, etc. */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.card{
  height: 40px;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-wrapper">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
  <div class="card">6</div>
  <div class="card">7</div>
  <div class="card">8</div>
  <div class="card">9</div>
</div>
```

Note that you can change the value for `grid-template-columns` with media queries to match the number of columns you want for narrower screens.